# How should I calculated a constant based on a set of experimental values?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

I was wondering about the following example: suppose I wish to determine the spring constant determined by swinging a mass to it's end. It is given by the following formula:

$$T=2\pi \sqrt\frac{M}{k}$$

where $T$ is the period of the spring with mass $M$ hanging from it. I have set of experimental values for $M$ and $T$. To calculate $k$, should I:

1) Find $\bar M, \bar T$, and sub it into the formula or,

2) Calculate $k_i$ for each set $(M_i, T_i)$, then calculate $k$ as the average of all $k_i$?

My personal thinking is the first method, because a regression line must pass through the mean values. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Neither options 1 or 2.  I would do the following:

1) Algebraically separate k in the given equation.

2) Measure the given mass on the most precise balance available.

3) Measure the amount of time that it takes to complete at least 20 cycles, and divide by 20 to arrive at T.  There is error in measuring the period, and this step divides that error by 20 (or more if more cycles are timed).

4) Use the measured data to calculate k from the equation that was derived in step 1.